# Android 5.0 Lollipop not working on Worklight 5.0.3

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, android-5.0-lollipop

We're running Worklight 5.0.3 and our app isn't working on the latest image of Lollipop.  The error we're getting is "All WebView methods must be called on the same thread, for DroidGap.  I assume this is based on the old version Cordova.

I know this is fixed in later versions of Worklight, but we're triyng to find a fix that doesn't involve an upgrade that we can get quicker.  Is there a way to patch/add a later version of Cordova with an older version of Worklight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the Cordova version that is generated by Worklight Studio and used within the Worklight Application.

This is even more emphasised in older versions of Worklight, like 5.0.0.3. There are no plans to support this version of Worklight.